# Can I assign a variable value to multiple attributes at once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I want to set horizontal padding of a styled element to variable 'x' and set vertical to a variable 'y'. Of course, this is possible:

```
var docex = document.getElementById.style;
docex.paddingTop = y;
docex.paddingBottom = y;
docex.paddingLeft = x;
docex.paddingRight = x;
```

Is there a shorter way for me to do this, such as something akin to:

```
var docex = document.getElementById.style;
docex.paddingTop = docex.paddingBottom = y;
docex.paddingLeft = docex.paddingRight = x;
```

However, as I understand it, the above would not work and would declare a global variable, as I saw from another question on this site. So, what would be the most efficient minimal way for me to implement an idea similar to above, that is possible with vanilla javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just introduce a function which accepts x,y and do the stuff inside the function

Comment: What global variable?

Comment: you can do some css trickery for that specific case -> `document.getElementById('#id').style.cssText='padding: '+x+' '+y;`

Comment: won't this override the current inline-style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, as I understand it, the above would not work and would declare a global variable

It wouldn't.

Compare these two examples:

---

```
var foo = bar = 2;
```

This:

1. Declares `foo` as a local variable
2. Assigns `2` to `bar` implicitly creating `bar` as a global while it does it
3. Assigns `bar` to `foo`

---

```
obj.foo = obj.bar = 2;
```

This:

1. Assigns `2` to `obj.bar` implicitly creating `bar` as a property of `obj` if it doesn't already exist
2. Assigns `obj.bar` to `obj.foo` implicitly creating `foo` as a property of `obj` if it doesn't already exist

It doesn't create a global because you don't have any code which mentions a variable name.

---

That said, since you are changing **all** the padding properties, you can set the `padding` shorthand property instead of doing each of the four individually.

```
padding: <top> <right> <bottom> <left>
```

or

```
padding: <vertical> <horizontal>
```

Thus:

```
docex.padding = y + " " + x;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shorthand CSS rule for that:

```
docex.padding = y + " " + x;
```

This sets `y` as top and bottom padding and `x` as left and right padding.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

Comment: Ah, yeah. This wasn't working for me earlier because I was writing it as docex.padding = y + x; without the space in quotation. And I didn't even know writing just two variables means that it assumes horizontal and vertical. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `style.padding`

```js
var x="50px";
var y="25px";

var ele = document.getElementById('o');

ele.style.padding = y+' '+x;
```

```css
#o{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#i{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="o">
<div id="i">
  </div></div>
```